# Reduce a multilevel JSON to an array of unique records

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to reduce a multilevel JSON to an array of unique records.

This is an example of the JSON:

`{ "id": { "v": "982W:811", "f": "811" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null }`

Every example I've found demonstrates reducing a simple array of strings/numbers or a single-level JSON object.

Below is my working code that works through 3 steps to find unique records and output in the JSON format required.

Is there there's a better way to do this?

Thank you for your assistance and understanding.

```js
//Array containing duplicates
var array = [
  { "id": { "v": "982W:811", "f": "811" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:811", "f": "811" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null }, //duplicate
  { "id": { "v": "982W:813", "f": "813" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:813", "f": "813" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null }, //duplicate
  { "id": { "v": "982W:831", "f": "831" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:831", "f": "831" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null } //duplicate
];
//console.log('array', array);
    
    
//Stringify the array 
var array_stringify = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array_stringify.push(JSON.stringify(array[i]));
}
//console.log('array_stringify', array_stringify);
     
//Create set from the array to remove duplicates and convert into an array of strings
var array_set = new Set(array_stringify);
var array_arryFromSet = Array.from(array_set);
//console.log('array_arryFromSet', array_arryFromSet);

//Parse each string into the original JSON format
var array_parse = [];
var push_value;
for (var i = 0; i < array_arryFromSet.length; i++) {
  push_value = JSON.parse(array_arryFromSet[i]);
  array_parse.push(push_value);
}
console.log('array_parse', array_parse);
    
/* array_parse RESULT            
[
  { "id": { "v": "982W:811", "f": "811" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:813", "f": "813" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:831", "f": "831" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null }
]    
*/
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your stringify approach you could cut the steps down by using one loop of the array and  adding to  set as you go , checking before you add if the item already exists or not.

Using `JSON.stringify()` however will not work if any property is not in same order as other elements in array and is typically not a recommended approach. Using a *"deep equal"* recursive function is far safer

```js
var array = [
  { "id": { "v": "982W:811", "f": "811" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:811", "f": "811" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null }, //duplicate
  { "id": { "v": "982W:813", "f": "813" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:813", "f": "813" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null }, //duplicate
  { "id": { "v": "982W:831", "f": "831" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:831", "f": "831" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null } //duplicate
];


var set = new Set()

var res = array.reduce((a, c)=>{
   var str = JSON.stringify(c)
   if(!set.has(str)){
       set.add(str)
       return a.concat(c);
   }   
   return a
},[])

console.log(res)
```

If you have enough of these sorts of operations would recommend using a library like lodash.js which would allow you to do this in a very simple one liner

```js
var array = [
  { "id": { "v": "982W:811", "f": "811" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:811", "f": "811" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null }, //duplicate
  { "id": { "v": "982W:813", "f": "813" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:813", "f": "813" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null }, //duplicate
  { "id": { "v": "982W:831", "f": "831" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:831", "f": "831" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null } //duplicate
];


var res = _.uniqWith(array, _.isEqual);

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.14/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have successfully tested with this JavaScript process.   Thank you for sharing the hint about lodash.js.  That looks like a handy library to have as a front end developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function to compare the nested object.

- Create a function which will take two objects.
- Iterate through the the keys of objects. Check if the same key of two objects is not same then return `false`
- Check if the values are other objects then call the function recursively on both the values.
- If no corresponding key is found unequal then return `true`
- Then use combination of `filter()` and `some()` to remove duplicates.

```js
const isObj = a => a && typeof a === "object"

function compare(obj1,obj2){
  if(Object.keys(obj1).length !== Object.keys(obj2).length) return false;
  for(let k in obj1){
    if([obj1[k], obj2[k]].every(isObj)){
      if(!compare(obj1[k],obj2[k])) return false;
    }
    else{
      if(obj1[k] !== obj2[k]) return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}



var array = [
  { "id": { "v": "982W:811", "f": "811" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:811", "f": "811" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null }, //duplicate
  { "id": { "v": "982W:813", "f": "813" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:813", "f": "813" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null }, //duplicate
  { "id": { "v": "982W:831", "f": "831" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null },
  { "id": { "v": "982W:831", "f": "831" }, "parent": "982W", "size": null } //duplicate
];

let res = array.filter((x,i) => array.slice(i+1).every(a => !compare(x,a)))
console.log(res)
```